# Postgresql cluster upgrade: preventing clashes in txid_current() and upgrading to pg_current_xact_id()

Tags: postgresql

I have a database with a table. In that table is a column `txid` which records metadata about the changes that occurred within that transaction:

```
 \d data.transactions
                                 Table "data.transactions"
      Column      |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |      Default
------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+--------------------
 id               | uuid                        |           | not null | uuid_generate_v4()
 txid             | bigint                      |           | not null | txid_current()
 at               | timestamp without time zone |           | not null | now()
 username         | text                        |           |          | "current_user"()
 username_session | text                        |           |          | "session_user"()
 comment          | text                        |           | not null | ''::text
 resource         | text                        |           | not null | 'records'::text
Indexes:
    "transactions_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "transactions_txid_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (txid)
Check constraints:
    "transactions_comment_check" CHECK (length(comment) < 64000)
Triggers:
    notify_of_updates_after_a_transaction_trg AFTER INSERT ON data.transactions DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION data.notify_of_updates_after_a_transaction_trg()
```

The workflow assumes that the `txid` returned by `txid_current()` will be unique in perpetuity of the lifetime of the product, which due to the epoch being embedded within the integer is true. Or at least, it would be true were we never to upgrade our Postgresql cluster. An upgrade for us is a pg_dump and restore on new physical hardware. In this case the txid_current() will start again at zero epoch and clashes, although unlikely, are very much possible.

Hopefully you can see the problem. It's not likely to be an issue, but if possible I want to fix it before it is.

My second problem is the deprecation of `txid_current()`. I really don't want to change the workflow in what is otherwise a working platform, but I can see that the function `txid_current()` is scheduled for removal in a future postgresql release so I will have to do something at some point. `txid_current()`'s replacement `pg_current_xact_id()` returns an 'integer' of type `xid8`. Because of this, the function is not a drop-in replacement for me (at least on Postgresql 14, which is what I am currently using).

```sql
=# select pg_current_xact_id()::bigint;
ERROR:  cannot cast type xid8 to bigint
LINE 1: select pg_current_xact_id()::bigint;
```

This txid column is a foreign key on many other tables, so changing its type is tricky, but not impossible.

Comment: The following workaround allows casting `xid8` to `bigint`: `select pg_current_xact_id(), pg_current_xact_id()::text::bigint, pg_typeof(pg_current_xact_id()::text::bigint);`. The result is `748,748,bigint`.

Comment: But on PostgreSQL forum it is mentioned that `xid8` is not kind of number: https://postgrespro.com/list/thread-id/2450723

Comment: Thanks for the txid_current()::text::xid8 trick. That seems to work. The problem about restarting at 0 seems to remain with pg_current_xact_id, possibly even worse given that it's just a straight up incrementing 64 bit integer so there's no epoch to avoid clashes.